# Meson build installed v 0.55.3 but on building pitivi it shows meson 0.53.0 is install and the build fails

Tags: compiling, ubuntu-gnome, pitivi

Meson build updated to version 0.55.3 but on building pitivi it shows meson 0.53.0 is install and the build fails, why is it not detecting the latest version.
Is there a path problem?
This build uses sandbox env is there a problem with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sandbox is built using `meson` from the Gnome flatpak runtime, which is `0.53.0`.

See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pitivi/-/commits/meson

Better to ask in our chat room about this.